# Automate erasing certain colors in multiple PSD files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, automation, selections, photoshop-scripting

Is it possible to erase all colors in the 2nd layer of a PSD file in Photoshop except yellow in one step?

I have multiple images. Should I use the hex code to preserve the yellow color?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to create an action to remove all colors except yellow. Then I'll create a script that get each ***.psd** files in **D:/myFolder** and will apply the action to second layer of each loaded file. Then I will save each file in the same path. so....

### First create an Action

1. Press Alt + F9 to open Action window
2. Click on "Create a set" button and rename it to **mySet**
   [image]
3. Click on "Create an Action" button and rename it to **myAction**
   [image]
4. Go to Select -> Color Range (selected Yellow) pressed OK
5. Press Ctrl + Shift + i (to inverse selection)
6. Hit Delete button on keyboard to delete the Selected colors
7. press CTRL + D to deselect the current selection

### Second create a Script

Create a folder in drive D and rename it to **myFolder** ("D:/myFolder") and copy & paste all psd files there. (Keep source files in another directory)

1. Open notepad and copy and paste the following code
2. Save the file with ".jsx" extention
3. Go to Photoshop -> File -> Scripts -> Browse... and select your
   script and run it

---

```
var inFolder = new Folder("D:/myFolder")
if(inFolder != null)
{
var fileList = inFolder.getFiles(/\.(tif|psd|)$/i);
}
for(var i = 0 ;i < fileList.length; i++)
{
var docRef = open(fileList[i]);
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[1];
app.doAction("myAction", "mySet");
doc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);
}
```

---

That's it

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in one step, but in a few perhaps.  Make a selection of the yellow colour using Select > Colour Range, and use the colour picker to select the yellow item, and adjust the fuzziness and range sliders until you get a good selection, then add a layer mask to the layer.

Example:

[image: Example image of using a layer mask]

Comment: Thank you. But as the yellow color is in random places I think I can't run it in batch process and that's where I need help.

Comment: You could select the "Yellows" preset from the dropdown in the colour range dialog.